# Extracting String Parts with Regular Expressions

Tags: regex

This is a string:
`http://news.ycombinator.com/page?vasya=pupkin&b=b  news.ycombinator.com/page news.ycombinator.com/page.php  news.ycombinator.com/page`

I am extracting a host with page. So I wrote the following regular expression:

```
([a-zA-Z0-9\.]*[a-zA-Z0-9]+[^\/][\.][a-zA-Z0-9\/\.]+)
```

It returns me these (in bold):

http://**news.ycombinator.com/page**?vasya=pupkin&b=b  **news.ycombinator.com/page**  **news.ycombinator.com/page.php**  **news.ycombinator.com/page**

This is not exactly what I need. Regexp should not see a host with page in case of this string: `http://news.ycombinator.com/page?vasya=pupkin&b=b`, because it is a link, which should be treated differently.

Should be rejected:

```
"http://news.ycombinator.com/page?vasya=pupkin&b=b", "http://news.ycombinator.com/page", "http://news.ycombinator.com/","http://news.ycombinator.com".
```

Should not be rejected:

```
"news.ycombinator.com/page","news.ycombinator.com/page.php", "news.ycombinator.com/page/index", "news.ycombinator.com/page/index.php"
```

**How to improve this regexp so it could select only those string parts, which have no word characters nearby?**

Comment: knock yourself out http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc3986#section-1.1.1 - are you sure what is meant by host? the optional http:// precedes some words separated by dots that makes the host name

Comment: http:// is a protocol, then goes host and then page after "/". After ? we have url parameters. In fact this doesn't matter that much. The main question is in bold.

Comment: the only difference that I see is that the url, which you mentioned, contains query part. Do you want to exclude urls with query?

Comment: urls with query should not be extracted as well.

Comment: another difference is the protocol ("http://")

Comment: @Max i don't really understand what you are asking sorry, can you give us examples of urls that should be rejected, and those that shouldn't?

Comment: updated the question upon your request

Comment: Maybe `[^ :/]+/[^ ?]+` would help you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure exactly what you are using to do your regex, but you've actually solved your own problem - you just need the regex to match whole words. This will depend on the program you are using, but this is a guidleine (posix style regex):

```
([:space:][a-zA-Z0-9\.]*[a-zA-Z0-9]+[^\/][\.][a-zA-Z0-9\/\.]+[:space:])

or maybe ([:space:]([a-zA-Z0-9]*[\.\/])+[a-zA-Z0-9]+[:space:])
```

In the second one, you will have to make sure the inner groups are for non capturing groups.